# Acrobat Eyedropper Tool

Tags: colors, adobe-acrobat

I have searched the Acrobat dialog and online for a plugin to select colors from a pdf using an eyedropper.

I need a tool to select hex color values from acrobat pdf's. Where can I find one? I am using Acrobat 9 Pro.

Comment: I can't help with acrobat 9, but [this](http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/9.1/Acrobat9_1_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Acrobat9_HTMLHelp&file=JS_API_AcroJS.88.260.html) might give you some ideas

Comment: wouldnt any of the "colorPicker" utility softwares for picking a color on any desktop screen anywhere work in acrobat the same way they will on any program  other than 3D renders and overlays?  I am not familiar with acrobat.

Answer (score 1):

Open the pdf with http://www.irfanview.com/ and when you click a pixel the colors are shown in the title bar:

[image: title bar screen shot]

Comment: Thanks for contributing this answer.  Your [answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) could be made even better by including some additional detail, such as explaining in what form the colors are represented or by including an example screenshot.  Welcome to Super User!